# Spring MVC + SPRING DATA JPA: unable to read property from jointable entity in jsp using jstl

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, jstl, spring-data-jpa, spring-portlet-mvc

I'm developing a liferay 7 portlet using spring mvc and spring data jpa in the persistence layer.
Data are persisted in a dedicated DB.

my pom

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>it.realt</groupId>
    <artifactId>trasparenza</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>trasparenza Portlet</name>
    <version>1.0</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <liferay.impl.version>2.3.0</liferay.impl.version> <!-- liferay kernel & implementation are different than liferay version starting from liferay 7 -->
        <spring.version>4.3.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate-validator-version>5.3.0.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
        <servlet.version>3.1.0</servlet.version>
        <portlet.version>2.0</portlet.version>
    </properties>



    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>internal-profile</id>
            <properties>
                <liferay.version>7.0-ga3</liferay.version>
                <liferay.maven.plugin.version>7.0-ga3</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
                <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>c:/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
                <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>c:/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
                <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>c:/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/lib/ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
                <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>c:/liferay-ce-portal-7.0-ga3/tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-data-releasetrain</artifactId>
                <version>Ingalls-RELEASE</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>    


    <dependencies>
        <!-- liferay 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.impl</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.impl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.liferay.portal</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.liferay.portal.kernel</artifactId>
            <version>${liferay.impl.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet and JSR -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.portlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>portlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${portlet.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>




        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc-portlet</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>-->

        <!-- spring data jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>  

        <!-- JPA Provider (Hibernate) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>  
        <!-- DataSource (HikariCP) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.el-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>        
        <!-- end spring data jpa -->     

        <!-- thymeleaf and dialects -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-validator-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1212.jre7</version>
        </dependency>


        <!-- test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>21.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava-collections</artifactId>
            <version>r03</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>trasparenza</finalName>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>7.0.0-m2</version>
                <!-- 
               <executions>
                       <execution>
                               <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                               <goals>
                                       <goal>build-css</goal>
                               </goals>
                       </execution>
               </executions>
                -->
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I have a many to many relationship with extra columns in the join table.

Entity A

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "procedimento")
    public class Procedimento {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "procedimento_seq")
        @SequenceGenerator(name = "procedimento_seq", sequenceName = "procedimento_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
        private Integer id;


        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "procedimento", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
        private List<ProcedimentoAzienda> aziendeProcedimento;

        @Transient
        private List<ProcedimentoAzienda> elencoRTIAziendeAggiudicatarie;

        @Transient
        private List<ProcedimentoAzienda> elencoAziende;    

        @Transient
        private List<List<ProcedimentoAzienda>> elencoRTIAziendePartecipanti;

        @Transient
        private ProcedimentoAzienda aziendaAggiudicataria;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy="procedimento", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private List<ProcedimentoImporti> elencoImporti = new ArrayList<ProcedimentoImporti>();

        @Transient
        private Double totaleImportoPagato = 0d;

        ...... getter and setter
}
```

Entity B

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "aziende")
public class Azienda {

    public final static String SESSO_MASCHIO = "M";
    public final static String SESSO_FEMMINA = "F";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "azienda_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "azienda_seq", sequenceName = "azienda_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "ragione_sociale")
    private String ragioneSociale;

    @Column(name = "codice_fiscale")
    private String codiceFiscale;

    @Column(name = "identificativo_estero")
    private String identificativoEstero;

    @Column(name = "partita_iva")
    private String partitaIva;

    .....getter and setter
}
```

Entity mapping the join table

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "procedimento_azienda")
class ProcedimentoAzienda implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "procedimento_id")
    private Procedimento procedimento;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "azienda_id")    
    private Azienda azienda;

    @Column(name = "cig")
    private String cig;

    @Column(name = "n_ragg")
    private Integer nRagg;

    @Column(name = "ruolo_ragg")
    private String ruoloRagg;

    @Column(name = "aggiudicatario")
    private boolean aggiudicatario;

    .....getter and setter
}
```

in my jsp i have

```
       .......
        <td>
            <c:if test="${null != item.aziendaAggiudicataria}" >
                ${item.aziendaAggiudicataria.azienda.ragioneSociale}
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${null != item.elencoRTIAziendeAggiudicatarie}">
                <c:forEach items="${item.elencoRTIAziendeAggiudicatarie}" var="item2" >
                    &ndash; ${item2.azienda.ragioneSociale}
                </c:forEach>

            </c:if>
        </td>
        .......
```

When executing i'm getting the error

```
09:10:05,404 ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-9][PortletRequestDispatcherImpl:261] javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'it.realt.trasparenza.services.procedimenti.ProcedimentoAzienda' does not have a readable property 'azienda'.
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'it.realt.trasparenza.services.procedimenti.ProcedimentoAzienda' does not have a readable property 'azienda'.
```

I get the error when trying to access every property in the jointable entity.

What's wrong in my implementation?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED.... i didn't see i forgot the "public" in ProcedimentoAzienda class